# PHP click count with mysqli

Tags: php, post, mysqli

I want to make a program what will count clicks after click button.

I have this code but it don't work. I use mysqli to connect to database and I use query to insert value to database and query to select from database.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <title>Click</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="#" method="post">
            <input type="submit" name="click" value="Klikni mě">
            <br>
            <?php
            if(isset($_POST["click"])){
                $connection=new mysqli("hidden","hidden","hidden","hidden");
                if($connection == false){
                    die("Sorry jako");
                }
                $query="INSERT INTO klik (klikcount) VALUES ('$klik')";
                if($connection->query($query) == false){
                    die("Promiň");
                }
                $sql="SELECT klikcount FROM klik";
                $result=$connection->query($sql);
                if($result->num_rows>0){
                    while($row=$result->fetch_assoc()){
                        echo $row["klikcount"];
                    }
                }
                $klik=$klik+1;
            }
            ?>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

thanks.

Comment: Any errors? What "dont work"?

Comment: `$klik` is not defined before you attempt to insert it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I try solve your code and I made some changes.

1. Change position of "$klik = $klik+1;"
2. Add another SELECT

My new code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Click</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="#" method="post">
            <input type="submit" name="click" value="Klikni mě">
            <br>
            <?php
            if(isset($_POST["click"])) {
                $connection = new mysqli("hidden","hidden","hidden","hidden");

                if($connection == false) {
                    die("Sorry jako");
                }

                $sql="SELECT klikcount FROM klik";
                $result=$connection->query($sql);

                if($result->num_rows > 0) {
                    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
                        $klik = $row["klikcount"];
                    }
                }

                $klik = $klik+1;
                $query = "INSERT INTO klik (klikcount) VALUES ('$klik')";

                if($connection->query($query) == false) {
                    die("Promiň");
                }

                $sql = "SELECT klikcount FROM klik";
                $result = $connection->query($sql);

                if($result->num_rows > 0) {
                    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                        echo $row["klikcount"];
                    }
                }
            }
            ?>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```